# REG: Cross Join or While Loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a requirement to show all available combination of records between two tables. we have used two approaches for that. a) Cross join b).Nest while Loop. In query execution plan both approaches shows similar execution time. Just need to know which approach is good in case of large amount of data.

Comment: In SGBDs always favor to SQL-based solution.

Comment: large amounts of data is not really an objective description.

Comment: If you are thinking about using cursor & while loop, it's bad design 90% of the time. And how big is big? If one table as 10,000 rows and the other has 20,000 rows, the result will be 200,000,000 rows. It can overwhelm your server very quickly.

Comment: But  Cross join also returns same amount of rows?

Comment: Yes a cross join returns a cartesian of two tables. This can be unbelievably slow with even a moderate amount of data because the resulting output row count grows exponentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When faced with a problem in sql and there are two solutions - one set-based, the other iterative, it is generally better to go with the set-based solution.

In this case, the set-based solution is the cross joins.  This is the more scalable approach, and will yield performance benefits in the future if you need to apply filters to the where clause.